# What is the difference between xen-linux-system-3.16.0-4-amd64 and xen-linux-system-amd64 in Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, xen

I'm looking to migrate to Debian 8 Jessie and new Xen. I see that there two xen-linux-system-* packages available in Jessie:

- xen-linux-system-3.16.0-4-amd64
- xen-linux-system-amd64

I have installed them, one at the time, and both install Xen Hypervisor version 4.4.1. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xen-linux-system-amd64` will just be a dependency on the latest version in the distribution, which is currently `xen-linux-system-3.16.0-4-amd64`.  Should a newer version be introduced at some point, `xen-linux-system-amd64` will have a dependency on that version instead.  If you want to stay on the old, specific version, install the 3.16.0-4 package instead.  This paradigm is common in the Debian package system.